# Linking multiple TransformBlocks to single BatchBlock TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I've built two pipelines using `TPL Dataflow`:

```
TransformBlock => TransformBlock => BatchBlock => ....

TransformBlock => BatchBlock => TransformBlock => ....
```

I want to accomplish

```
            / => Transform Block => TransformBlock => BatchBlock => ....
BatchBlock /
           \
            \ => Transform Block => BatchBlock => TransformBlock => ....
```

However only the first pipeline gets executed.

My code

```
batchMediaBlock.LinkTo(pipelineA.FirstBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});
batchMediaBlock.LinkTo(pipelineB.FirstBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want the initial `BatchBlock` to send each message to both pipelines, or to send it only to the one that is less busy?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a `BroadcastBlock` after your `BatchBlock`. But be advised, completion will only propagate to one of your `TransformBlock`s. See below for a partial example to handle completion:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace MyDataflow {
    class MyDataflow {

        public void HandlingCompletion() {
            var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(10);
            var broadcastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<int[]>(_ => _);
            var xForm1 = new TransformBlock<int[], int[]>(_ => _);
            var xForm2 = new TransformBlock<int[], int[]>(_ => _);

            batchBlock.LinkTo(broadcastBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
            broadcastBlock.LinkTo(xForm1);
            broadcastBlock.LinkTo(xForm1);

            broadcastBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(broadcastBlockCompletionTask => {
                if (!broadcastBlockCompletionTask.IsFaulted) {
                    xForm1.Complete();
                    xForm2.Complete();
                }else {
                    ((IDataflowBlock)xForm1).Fault(broadcastBlockCompletionTask.Exception);
                    ((IDataflowBlock)xForm2).Fault(broadcastBlockCompletionTask.Exception);
                }

            });

            xForm1.Completion.ContinueWith(async _ => {
                try {
                    await xForm2.Completion;
                    //continue passing completion / fault on to rest of pipeline
                } catch  {

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if your pipeline never converges again you can handle completion separately for each pipeline after continuing the `BroacastBlock`. The example provided will complete each step in the pipeline at the same time, flowing completion along in sync.

Answer (score 2):

By default, linking in TPL Dataflow is considered greedy, so the first target always get message **and** removes it from previous block' output, that's why your second block doesn't get any messages. Such situations can be addressed by [`BroadcastBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447.aspx), which

> ensures that the current element is broadcast **to any** linked targets before allowing the element to be overwritten.

You also should note that this block **do clone** the message.

So you basically should add a broadcast after your batch block, but! you should not propagate your completion from broadcast block to consumers - only first one will get a completion. You should add a `ContinueWith` handler for your broadcast, as @JSteward suggested.